How to merge or combine statechart and process flow in AnyLogic
My intention is to measure the queue, facility utilization and time in system. I have a statechart in Person agent tab, people start from home location, moving to facility (pharmacy) and return to home. Once they reach to facility, I want to measure queue and utilization of facility. For that, I created a flow enter > service > exit. In the pharmacy state, I wrote "enter1.take(this)". I was expecting people will enter the flow once they reach at pharmacy, but I found only the first person entering the flow. what's wrong with others? Also, I want once they are served, they should come to the statechart again, I have an arc from pharmacy state to home where I want people will go back to home again. Is there any logical flaw here and how they will return from process flow to statechart? People and pharmacy are set in GIS regions in main agent. See, attached picture. 

You are not taking an agent-based perspective yet. Each of your Person agents has the statechart AND the process flow "inside them" (assuming your screenshot shows the Person agent type)
So if 1 person calls enter1.take(this), all it does is sending itself into the flow that is inside itself.
it is as if John tells himself "John, its time to visit your internal organs" :)
You need a separate Pharmacy agent with the flow chart and resource pool and send your Person agents there. Learn the details of model hierarchy and study all of the step-by-step tutorials, they apply these concepts a lot.
PS: if your screenshot shows Main, then you need to create a Person population on Main as well and embed the statechart there :)
